# Cocoa Mac OSX: no errors in Debug mode but lot of errors in Release mode...Help !

Tags: cocoa, xcode, debugging, release, compiler-errors

My OSX program works perfectly well in debug mode. I wanted to "compile and archive" it for release but I have got plenty of errors which appear just in this mode.

For example :

```
NSButton *showMenuButton =  [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)];
```

gives :

**error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'initWithFrame:'**

Most of my erros are linked to `initWithFrame` method for different classes (`NSView, NSImageView...`)

Do you know what can be the origin of this issue ?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: A suggestion from this post is to change `CGRectMake` to `NSMakeRect` http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=47 . Give it a try.

Comment: @Mahesh You should make that an answer, not a comment. You can't be accepted for a comment.

Comment: @user395869 @ughoavgfhw Quoted the suggestion as answer. I don't know whether it would work because I didn't test it. Glad if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some issues of this kind in CorePlot, a ticket is opened. It is however marked as **fixed** with this modification but how ever I didn't find a permanent solution.

**Change `CGRectMake` to `NSMakeRect`** according to this [CorePlot Issue Post](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=47). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly ! I have also replaced all the CGPoint by NSPoint and all CGMakePoint by NSPointMake in order to remove all errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are importing the CoreGraphics header everywhere you need it.

If you are importing it in your prefix header (as I recommend you do with all the system framework headers you import), make sure that that build setting is set, and set to the correct file, in both of your configurations in the project or target where you set it.

Examples of how you might have that wrong:

- You have the prefix header set in the target, but only in Debug, so in Release, it inherits the (wrong) value from the project.
- You have it set in the target in both configurations, but to different values.
- You have it set in the project, but only in Debug, so in Release, it uses the (incorrect) default value.
- You have it set in the project in both configurations, but to different values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Peter. I used the solution given by Mahesh. Perhaps your solution works but only if the problem occurs with iOS applications as the CoreGraphics framework doesn't exist on Mac OS as far as I know.

Comment: @user395869: Core Graphics was introduced with Mac OS X, so it has always existed in Mac OS X.